# select input in Contact Form 7 option name instead of option value in email template

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I got a form created in Contact Form 7 in Wordpress.

```
<div class="col-12">
<label class="sr-only" for="zgloszenie-cena">Cena szkolenia</label>
[select* zgloszenie-cena id:zgloszenie-cena]
</div>
```

And in template where email is sent is code like this:

```
Lista szkolenia: [lista-szkolenia]
```

And why in email is value of this option select input not a name? how to change to display name of option not value.

Lista szkoleń: NAME instead of Lista szkoleń: OPTION

Answer (score 0):

So the normal use case for CF7 is to use values as names, meaning you only have one value:

```
[select* zgloszenie-cena id:zgloszenie-cena "Firefox" "Safari" "Opera" "Lynx"]
```

Comment: so i need to add names at the end, and CF7 will generate id for him it self ? I don`t even have possiblity to edit it, where to setup any options of this select input ?

Comment: When you select the field type on top of the editor, a popup should appear. But you can use my syntax if you want.

Comment: yes, but this select input goes from database, and to the email template system get value not name of the option and this is what i need to achive.